# 「より良いコードを提示してください」などのコードレビュー系の質問は認められますか？

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

スタックオーバーフローはプログラミングに関する質問のサイトですが、コードの理解が不足している初心者がより良いコードを求めて質問をしてきた場合、それはスタックオーバーフローではその質問は認められるのでしょうか？

具体的にはコードレビューをして欲しがっていたり、コードをよりよく修正してほしいなどの質問です。プログラマーにとってより良いコードを書くことはプログラミングの知識を深めるためにQAとして質問することと同じくらい重要なはずですが、スタックオーバーフローでそのような質問をしてもいいのでしょうか？

また、よりよいコードを書くためにコードを共有するなどのサービスなどはないのでしょうか？ たとえばGitHubなどがこれに該当するかもしれませんが、GitHubにプッシュするほどの大きなプロジェクトでなくともコードをレビューしてもらいたいときはどのような方法をとればよいのか知りたいです。

Comment: 重複候補: [コードレビュー的な質問はどこまでOKですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2939)

Comment: 単に「より良い」だと感覚的な話に過ぎないので、「実行速度を改善したい」などの **プログラム視点で具体的** な聞き方であれば OK なのかなと思っています。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### コードをレビューしてもらいたいときの方法

ひとつ確実な回答として、英語でよろしければ「スタック・オーバーフロー」と同じく Stack Exchange 系列のサイトとして [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) があります。

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

> **Code Review** is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code. We are working together to improve the skills of programmers worldwide by taking working code and making it better.

### スタック・オーバーフローにおけるコードレビュー

ここからはコミュニティの中で広く合意がとれているとまでは言えないことですが、「スタック・オーバーフロー」の中ではコードレビュー的な質問の中にはオフトピックなものもあると思っています。

スタック・オーバーフローのヘルプ https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask には以下のように書かれています。

> 一部の主観的な質問は許されますが、「主観的」とは「何でもあり」という意味ではありません。すべての主観的な質問は建設的であることが期待されます。

このヘルプに沿って考えると、単に「このコードで良いですか？」と聞くような質問はあまり建設的ではなく、オフトピック気味と言えるでしょう。一方で「このコードをクラスベースのオブジェクト指向で表そうとして○○の部分で困ったのですがどうすれば良いですか？」のような質問はオントピックでしょう。

「このコードで良いですか？」というようなオフトピック気味な質問は、スタック・オーバーフロー的には、何故そのコードが良くないと思ったのかの原因をコメントで分析して、うまく建設的な方向に持っていくのが良いのかなぁ、とも思っています。